# LaTeX structure

Tags: tex-core, latex-misc

I have question about LaTeX structure and how LaTeX works? Is it just a set of macros for TeX? What happens, when I call `latex somefile.tex`? Does `latex` just includes `somefile` into a file, which contain basic LaTeX macros and calls `tex`?

I've looked at `latex.ltx`. There are some commands, which are neither defined nor basic TeX commands. Does LaTeX introduce new fundamental commands, which TeX haven't?

Comment: Do http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/what-are-tex-and-latex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/latex-architecture-how-does-it-all-work answer your questions?

Comment: After looking at the questions linked by Caramdir, I suggest asking a more specific question. A generic question such as "how das LaTeX work" might require an extensive general introductional text, so expect links to such texts. Specific questions could get concrete answers.

Comment: Thanks @Caramdir for the links. Especially [LaTeX architecture - how does it all work?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/latex-architecture-how-does-it-all-work) seems to be quite similar. I myself would love to get an in-deep technical explanation how exactly `[pdf]latex` is based on `tex`. Is it simply a format? Are the LaTeX macros build in an own variant of the TeX compiler? Is `latex.ltx` really read for every `latex` run?

Comment: @Martin -- latex is simply a format.  (plain is the original format.)  there are others, e.g. context.  pdftex is a modification/extension to the tex engine; pdflatex uses the pdftex engine with the latex format preloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

latex is (in essence) a collection of macros.

a file containing these macros is read by tex (in initialisation mode --
flag "--ini" on tex-live versions of tex).

at the end of reading the file, tex encounters a \dump command, and writes a
"format" file latex.fmt

the latex *command* is defined to "run tex and load latex.fmt".  simple...

latex's collection of macros covers most of what plain tex (knuth's format)
does, but adds a bunch of extensions that allow the user to impose some regular
structure on a document.